# Format USB drive as CDFS

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program I want to run from a USB drive. I have a sample of one that does this very thing and I want to do it with my software. There is a small partition that is in CDFS format and the rest is in FAT. The CDFS format autoruns in a windows system and that is what I am wanting to do. Have the ability to create a partition on a USB drive and have a windows based PC see it as CDFS.

Comment: Authority to do this was revoked by Microsoft due to massive abuse by malware authors.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably misunderstanding how your sample one works.

Formatting a USB stick as CDFS won't work - this has been tried many times (including by me) and Windows simply refuses to mount the file system.

The USB drives that work this way are normally implemented by registering two USB devices when they're plugged in: the first corresponds to a CDROM-type device (complete with a CDFS filesystem). The second is the normal USB Mass Storage device.

In other words, it's a hardware issue, not a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the USB drive file system by yourself, it's not enough to cheat Windows and to instruct it to run autorun.inf. You have to use a special type of USB drive called U3, start from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3).